# Android корневая папка проекта

Tags: android, io, filestream

Есть поле:

```
private static final String JSON_FILE = "team.json";
```

Есть инициализация потока:

```
fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(JSON_FILE);
```

По какому пути в проекте должен лежать team.json?

Comment: например в /assets. при первом запуске он должен быть скопирован оттуда в папку приложения для работы с файлами   (обычно это */data/data/название_пакета/files/*) - это каталог на устройстве для файлов приложения по умолчанию. Точный путь возвращает метод getFilesDir() класса Context

Comment: Папки assets нет, где ее нужно добавить?

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php

Comment: Такого варианта нет.

Comment: какого варианта нет? попытайтесь излагать свою проблему так,чтобы она была понятна и людям, которые имеют о ней представление только с ваших слов

Comment: Извините, мне стоило получше поискать как добавить папку assets.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было вручную создать папку /assets в проекте по пути  /app/src/main.